# How can I completely reset my terminal theme?

Tags: command-line, gnome, themes

I had been using pywal for a while time and decided that I just wanted a complete reboot on all the themes I have used for it. So before uninstall pywal I had cleared its cache, and performed Wal -R, uninstalled pywal from my computer however nothing seemed to actually reset at all. My terminal is still exactly the same as it was when I used pywal, and even the terminal themes on vscode for example are still using pywal themes. I am not sure how I can fix this, could it be possible that my terminal is fetching the colors somewhere even when pywal has been uninstalled?

Comment: try removing the ~/.cache/wal dir: `rm -rf  ~/.cache/wal`